# Display Metadata from icecast server in Android App

Tags: android, metadata

I want to get the metadata information from one of icecast streaming servers and display such data in my Android Application. Any recommendation?

using the below code , I am not able to get the full metadata ( artist and the title ....)

code

```
String  stringUrl="http://dev.kigen.co:8000/xrm-ele.opus";

URL url = null;
try {
    url = new URL(stringUrl);
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
URLConnection cn = null;
try {
    cn = url.openConnection();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}   
try {
    cn.connect();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}   

int pos=1;
String x;
String y;

while (cn.getHeaderField(pos) != null) { 
    x=cn.getHeaderFieldKey(pos); 
    y = cn.getHeaderField(x); 
    System.out.println(":::::"+""+x+" : "+y); 
    pos++; 
}
```

}

generated output

```
:::::Server : Steamcast Distributed Network Media Server/1.0.0 decennium (Windows 64-bit)
:::::Date : Sat, 24 Oct 2015 16:52:16 GMT
:::::Connection : Keep-Alive
:::::Content-Type : application/ogg
:::::Cache-Control : max-age=0, no-cache, no-store
:::::Expires : Mon, 25 Jan 2002 10:11:57 GMT
:::::Pragma : no-cache
:::::ice-name : [XRM] - Electronic
:::::ice-genre : Electronic, Dance, Trance
:::::ice-url : http://www.xrm.fm/
:::::ice-public : 1
:::::ice-bitrate : 64
:::::ice-description : XRM Electronic in OGG Opus
:::::ice-audio-info : 
:::::Transfer-Encoding : chunked
:::::Set-Cookie : __steam_sess=8134e975470ac65a-5edd5a42-4a1b-6f58-87d4e64dc919bc08fb1821b0; path=/
```

Answer (score 0):

I see your using my Steamcast server.  This is not Icecast and as such is a bit different.  However, the biggest problem is you are using an Opus stream.  These are OGG encapsulated streams.  You could try using [android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html) to retrieve the metadata.  Different version of Android have different capabilities.  So it might not work correctly on all versions.

Comment: Could you please provide an example.